# WHMCS module for managing ISPConfig

Tags: hosting, ubuntu-16.04, whmcs, ispconfig-3

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with ISPConfig 3.1 and a website where I installed WHMCS.

My goal is to use [this module](https://github.com/cwispy/ispcfg3) that integrates WHMCS with ISPConfig 3.1 allowing the automatic creation, termination, suspension, and un-suspension of accounts.

But I'm kind of confused.

Is it ok to install WHMCS on a webiste from the own server to be managed (e.g. for client2, site2), or do I have to install it somewhere else? If so, where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing it should be ok to install WHMCS on the same server.

But for production, it is better for performance and security to install WHMCS on separate server or hosting.